# tailwind cli does not work after everything is done right. even the default button is blank

Tags: html, css, npm, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

[the document and all of my packages (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0nHM.png)

I tried it with the cdn and that worked but why cant I use it fine with the cli

Comment: What doesn't work? Any errors? What commands are you running? Need a lot more information.

Comment: the styles dont work, the fonts arent showing up, everything is just blank. all of the commands seem to have worked and look fine.

Comment: What are the commands than you ran though ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `tailwind.config.js`. Try replacing it with the code below

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```